# Multiple "sed" actions on previous results

Tags: bash, sed

Have this input:

```
bar foo
foo ABC/DEF
BAR ABC
ABC foo DEF
foo bar
```

on the above I need do 4 (sequential) actions:

- select only lines containing "foo" (lowercase)
- on the selected lines, remove everything but UPPERCASE letters
- delete empty lines (if some is created by the previous action)
- and on the remaining from the above - enclose every char with `[x]`

I'm able to solve the above, but need two `sed` invocations piped together. Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
data() {
cat <<EOF
bar foo
foo ABC/DEF
BAR ABC
ABC foo DEF
foo bar
EOF
}

echo "Result OK"
data | sed -n '/foo/s/[^A-Z]//gp' | sed '/^\s*$/d;s/./[&]/g'

# in the above it is solved using 2 sed invocations
# trying to solve it using only one invocation,
# but the following doesn't do what i need.. :( :(

echo "Variant 2 - trying to use only ONE invocation of sed"
data | sed -n '/foo/s/[^A-Z]//g;/^\s*$/d;s/./[&]/gp'
```

output from the above:

```
Result OK
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
Variant 2 - trying to use only ONE invocation of sed
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
[B][A][R][ ][A][B][C]
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
```

The variant 2 should be also only

```
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
```

It is possible to solve the above using only by one `sed` invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/foo/{s/[^A-Z]//g;/^$/d;s/./[&]/g;p;}' inputfile
```

Output:

```
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
```

Comment: Nice, thanx  (need to learn what the `{...}` means). It works using GNU sed - is possible a solution with BSD (macos x) sed too?:)

Comment: Yes, BSD, MacOS, and all `sed` versions have brackets.

Comment: hm.. it prints `sed: 1: "/foo/{s/[^A-Z]//g;/^$/d ...": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: found it `sed -n '/foo/{s/[^A-Z]//g;/^$/d;s/./[&]/g;p;}'` needs `;` after the `p`! THANX!!!

Comment: *GNU* `sed` doesn't seem to require that last `;` after the `p`, but it works with it, so it's now been added for portability.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/foo/!d;s/[^A-Z]//g;/./!d;s/./[&]/g' file
```

The output:

```
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
[A][B][C][D][E][F]
```

---

`/foo/!d` - deletes all lines that don't contain `foo`

`/./!d` - deletes all empty lines